# How to have both Zoom and drag functionality in d3 force layout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css, d3.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="../D3/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <style>
        body
         {
            background-color: #3F51B5;
         }

        svg:not(.active):not(.ctrl) 
       {
           cursor: crosshair;
        }

        path.link
         {
            fill: none;
            stroke: floralwhite;
            stroke-width: 4px;
            cursor: default;
        }

        svg:not(.active):not(.ctrl) path.link 
        {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        path.link.selected 
        {
            stroke-dasharray: 10,2;
        }

        path.link.dragline
         {
            pointer-events: none;
        }

        path.link.hidden
         {
            stroke-width: 0;
        }

        rect.node 
        {
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        rect.node.reflexive 
            {
                stroke: #000 !important;
                stroke-width: 2.5px;
            }

        text {
            font: 12px sans-serif;
            pointer-events: none;
             }

            text.id 
            {
                text-anchor: middle;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        // set up SVG for D3
        var width = 1400,
            height = 800,
            colors = d3.scale.category10();


        var svg = d3.select('body')
          .append('svg')
          .attr('oncontextmenu', 'return false;')
          .attr('width', width)
          .attr('height', height)
        .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw))
        .append('g');



        // set up initial nodes and links
        //  - nodes are known by 'id', not by index in array.
        //  - reflexive edges are indicated on the node (as a bold black rect).
        //  - links are always source < target; edge directions are set by 'left' and 'right'.


     var nodes = [
   {
       "id": "Component",
       "description": "Component are the Containers",
       "type": "wiring"
   },
   {
       "id": "Form Design And Data Design",
       "description": "In the Form Design and Data Design we can create form and data",
       "type": "wiring"
   },
   {
       "id": "Data and Property ",
       "description": "All the Data has the Property and value Associated with It",
       "type": "wiring"
   },
   {
       "id": "Entity Query",
       "description": "Entity Queries can be used to create Entity Relationship ",
       "type": "wiring"
   },
   {
       "id": "Entity Query and Entity Data",
       "description": "Entity Data Can be used to create ",
       "type": "wiring"
   }
     ],

          lastNodeId = 2,
          links = [

          ];



     //var k = Math.sqrt(nodes.length / (width * height));


          // init D3 force layout
        var force = d3.layout.force()
            .nodes(nodes)
            .links(links)
            .size([width, height])
            .linkDistance(250)
            .charge(-1000)
            .gravity(0.05)
            //.charge(-10 / k)
           // .gravity(100 * k)
            //.linkStrength(5)
            .theta(1)
            .alpha(3)
            .on('tick', tick)



        /// define arrow markers for graph links
        svg.append('svg:defs').append('svg:marker')
            .attr('id', 'end-arrow')
            .attr('viewBox', '0 -5 10 10')
            .attr('refX', 6)
            .attr('markerWidth', 5)
            .attr('markerHeight', 5)
            .attr('orient', 'auto')
          .append('svg:path')
            .attr('d', 'M0,-5L10,0L0,5')
            .attr('fill', 'red');

        svg.append('svg:defs').append('svg:marker')
            .attr('id', 'start-arrow')
            .attr('viewBox', '0 -5 10 10')
            .attr('refX', 6)
            .attr('markerWidth', 5)
            .attr('markerHeight', 5)
            .attr('orient', 'auto')
          .append('svg:path')
            .attr('d', 'M10,-5L0,0L10,5')
            .attr('fill', 'red');








        // line displayed when dragging new nodes
        var drag_line = svg.append('svg:path')
          .attr('class', 'link dragline hidden')
          .attr('d', 'M0,0L0,0');


        // handles to link and node element groups
        var path = svg.append('svg:g').selectAll('path'),


            rect = svg.append('svg:g').selectAll('g');

        // mouse event vars
        var selected_node = null,
            selected_link = null,
            mousedown_link = null,
            mousedown_node = null,
            mouseup_node = null;




        //function for Zoom and pan
        function redraw() {
            svg.attr("transform",
                "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")"
                + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
        }


        var drag = force.stop().drag()
                       .on("dragstart", function (d) {
                           d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();     // to prevent pan functionality from 
                                                                       //overriding node drag functionality.
                                                                       // put any other 'dragstart' actions here
                       });


        function wrapText(text, width) {
            text.each(function () {
                var textEl = d3.select(this),
                    words = textEl.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
                    word,
                    line = [],
                    linenumber = 0,
                    lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
                    y = textEl.attr('y'),
                    dx = parseFloat(textEl.attr('dx') || 0),
                    dy = parseFloat(textEl.attr('dy') || 0),
                    tspan = textEl.text(null).append('tspan').attr('x', 0).attr('y', y).attr('dy', dy + 'em');

                while (word = words.pop()) {
                    line.push(word);
                    tspan.text(line.join(' '));
                    if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
                        line.pop();
                        tspan.text(line.join(' '));
                        line = [word];
                        tspan = textEl.append('tspan').attr('x', 0).attr('y', y).attr('dx', dx).attr('dy', ++linenumber * lineHeight + dy + 'em').text(word);
                    }
                }
            });
        }



        function resetMouseVars() {
            mousedown_node = null;
            mouseup_node = null;
            mousedown_link = null;
        }

        // update force layout (called automatically each iteration)
        function tick() {
            // draw directed edges with proper padding from node centers
            path.attr('d', function (d) {
                var deltaX = d.target.x - d.source.x,
                    deltaY = d.target.y - d.source.y,
                    dist = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY),
                    normX = deltaX / dist,
                    normY = deltaY / dist,
                    sourcePadding = d.left ? 17 : 12,
                    targetPadding = d.right ? 17 : 12,
                    sourceX = d.source.x + (sourcePadding * normX),
                    sourceY = d.source.y + (sourcePadding * normY),
                    targetX = d.target.x - (targetPadding * normX),
                    targetY = d.target.y - (targetPadding * normY),
                    midX = (targetX - sourceX) / 2 + sourceX,
                    midY = (targetY - sourceY) / 2 + sourceY;
                //return 'M' + sourceX + ',' + sourceY + 'L' + targetX + ',' + targetY;
                return 'M' + sourceX + ',' + sourceY + 'L' + midX + ',' + midY + 'L' + targetX + ',' + targetY;
            });

            rect.attr('transform', function (d) {
                return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
            });
        }


        // update graph (called when needed)
        function restart() {
            // path (link) group
            path = path.data(links);

            // update existing links
            path.classed('selected', function (d) { return d === selected_link; })
                .style('marker-mid', function (d) { return d.left ? 'url(#start-arrow)' : 'url(#end-arrow)'; })


            // add new links
            path.enter().append('svg:path')
              .attr('class', 'link')
              .classed('selected', function (d) { return d === selected_link; })
              .style('marker-mid', function (d) { return d.left ? 'url(#start-arrow)' : 'url(#end-arrow)'; })
              .on('mousedown', function (d) {
                  if (d3.event.ctrlKey) return;

                  // select link
                  mousedown_link = d;
                  if (mousedown_link === selected_link) selected_link = null;
                  else selected_link = mousedown_link;
                  selected_node = null;
                  restart();
              });


            // remove old links
            path.exit().remove();



            // rect (node) group
            // NB: the function arg is crucial here! nodes are known by id, not by index!
            rect = rect.data(nodes, function (d) { return d.id; });


            // update existing nodes (reflexive & selected visual states)
            rect.selectAll('rect')
                .style('fill', function (d) { return (d === selected_node) ? d3.rgb(colors(d.id)).brighter().toString() : colors(d.id); })
                .classed('reflexive', function (d) { return d.reflexive; });


            // add new nodes
            var g = rect.enter().append('svg:g');


            //g.append('svg:rect')
            //  .attr('class', 'node')
            //  .attr('r', 30)
            g.append('svg:rect')
          .attr('class', 'node')
          .attr('width', 150)
          .attr("height", 60)
          .attr("rx", 30)
          .attr("ry", 30)
          .attr("x", -75)
          .attr("y", -16.5)
          .style('fill', function (d) { return (d === selected_node) ? d3.rgb(colors(d.id)).brighter().toString() : colors(d.id); })
          .style('stroke', function (d) { return d3.rgb(colors(d.id)).darker().toString(); })
          .classed('reflexive', function (d) { return d.reflexive; })
          .on('mouseover', function (d) {
                  if (!mousedown_node || d === mousedown_node) return;
                  // enlarge target node
                  d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'scale(1.1)');
              })
           .on('mouseout', function (d) {
                  if (!mousedown_node || d === mousedown_node) return;
                  // unenlarge target node
                  d3.select(this).attr('transform', '');
              })
            .on('mousedown', function (d) {
                  if (d3.event.ctrlKey) return;

                  // select node
                  mousedown_node = d;
                  if (mousedown_node === selected_node) selected_node = null;
                  else selected_node = mousedown_node;
                  selected_link = null;

                  // reposition drag line
                  drag_line
                    .style('marker-end', 'url(#end-arrow)')
                    .classed('hidden', false)
                    .attr('d', 'M' + mousedown_node.x + ',' + mousedown_node.y + 'L' + mousedown_node.x + ',' + mousedown_node.y);

                  restart();
              })
              .on('mouseup', function (d) {
                  if (!mousedown_node) return;

                  // needed by FF
                  drag_line
                    .classed('hidden', true)
                    .style('marker-end', '');

                  // check for drag-to-self
                  mouseup_node = d;
                  if (mouseup_node === mousedown_node) { resetMouseVars(); return; }

                  // unenlarge target node
                  d3.select(this).attr('transform', '');

                  // add link to graph (update if exists)
                  // NB: links are strictly source < target; arrows separately specified by booleans
                  var source, target, direction;
                  if (mousedown_node.id < mouseup_node.id) {
                      source = mousedown_node;
                      target = mouseup_node;
                      direction = 'right';
                  } else {
                      source = mouseup_node;
                      target = mousedown_node;
                      direction = 'left';
                  }

                  var link;
                  link = links.filter(function (l) {
                      return (l.source === source && l.target === target);
                  })[0];

                  if (link) {
                      link[direction] = true;
                  } else {
                      link = { source: source, target: target, left: false, right: false };
                      link[direction] = true;
                      links.push(link);
                  }

                  // select new link
                  selected_link = link;
                  selected_node = null;
                  restart();
              });

            // show node IDs
            g.append('svg:text')
                .attr('x', 0)
                .attr('y', 4)
                .attr('class', 'id')
                .text(function (d) { return d.id; })
                .call(wrapText, 150);

            // remove old nodes
            rect.exit().remove();

            // set the graph in motion
            force.start();
        }

        function mousedown() {
            // prevent I-bar on drag
            //d3.event.preventDefault();

            // because :active only works in WebKit?
            svg.classed('active', true);

            if (d3.event.ctrlKey || mousedown_node || mousedown_link) return;

            // insert new node at point
            var point = d3.mouse(this),
                node = { id: ++lastNodeId, reflexive: false };
            node.x = point[0];
            node.y = point[1];
            nodes.push(node);

            restart();
        }

        function mousemove() {
            if (!mousedown_node) return;

            // update drag line
            drag_line.attr('d', 'M' + mousedown_node.x + ',' + mousedown_node.y + 'L' + d3.mouse(this)[0] + ',' + d3.mouse(this)[1]);

            restart();
        }

        function mouseup() {
            if (mousedown_node) {
                // hide drag line
                drag_line
                  .classed('hidden', true)
                  .style('marker-end', '');
            }

            // because :active only works in WebKit?
            svg.classed('active', false);

            // clear mouse event vars
            resetMouseVars();
        }

        function spliceLinksForNode(node) {
            var toSplice = links.filter(function (l) {
                return (l.source === node || l.target === node);
            });
            toSplice.map(function (l) {
                links.splice(links.indexOf(l), 1);
            });
        }

        // only respond once per keydown
        var lastKeyDown = -1;

        function keydown() {
            //d3.event.preventDefault();

            if (lastKeyDown !== -1) return;
            lastKeyDown = d3.event.keyCode;

            // ctrl
            if (d3.event.keyCode === 17) {
                rect.call(force.drag);
                svg.classed('ctrl', true);
            }

            if (!selected_node && !selected_link) return;
            switch (d3.event.keyCode) {
                case 8: // backspace
                case 46: // delete
                    if (selected_node) {
                        nodes.splice(nodes.indexOf(selected_node), 1);
                        spliceLinksForNode(selected_node);
                    } else if (selected_link) {
                        links.splice(links.indexOf(selected_link), 1);
                    }
                    selected_link = null;
                    selected_node = null;
                    restart();
                    break;
                case 66: // B
                    if (selected_link) {
                        // set link direction to both left and right
                        selected_link.left = true;
                        selected_link.right = true;
                    }
                    restart();
                    break;
                case 76: // L
                    if (selected_link) {
                        // set link direction to left only
                        selected_link.left = true;
                        selected_link.right = false;
                    }
                    restart();
                    break;
                case 82: // R
                    if (selected_node) {
                        // toggle node reflexivity
                        selected_node.reflexive = !selected_node.reflexive;
                    } else if (selected_link) {
                        // set link direction to right only
                        selected_link.left = false;
                        selected_link.right = true;
                    }
                    restart();
                    break;
            }
        }

        function keyup() {
            lastKeyDown = -1;

            // ctrl
            if (d3.event.keyCode === 17) {
                rect
                   .on('mousedown.drag', null)
                   .on('touchstart.drag', null);
                svg.classed('ctrl', false);
            }
        }

        // app starts here
        svg.on('mousedown', mousedown)
          .on('mousemove', mousemove)
          .on('mouseup', mouseup);
        d3.select(window)
          .on('keydown', keydown)
          .on('keyup',keyup);
        restart();



    </script>
</body>`enter code here`

</html>
```

Hi Alto....I wanted help in adding pan and zoom with Drag functionality also..

but Currently my zoom is only working
..I'm not  able to click and drag link from node to node.I think my pan and zoom function is preventing Drag function to work...
kindly please help me to have them both...

Comment: See http://bl.ocks.org/eyaler/10586116

Comment: Hi Lars..Let Me Study what ever..I want from that Example and Revert back to you..If i have any doubts... Its really very helpful..but it takes time for me to understand them as I'm new to D3.js

Comment: Hi Lars..the block was really helpful...I have understanded most of it..but right now I need to have Tool tip for my node which on mouse over any node should display  some msg...and also I want the shape of the Tool tip to be custom one which is drawn by myself instead of square or rect box...please advice me on this..

Comment: I'm sure you'll be able to find lots of examples of D3 tooltips with just a bit of searching.